# node_publish_action is not publishing the node

Tags: forms, actions, nodes

I'm trying to add a submit handler to a "Done" button that should publish a node when the button is pressed. It's a scenario where the Rules module won't cut it, it has to be in code. I tried to following:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form['#form_id'] == 'my_node_form'){
    if ($form['actions']['done'] !== NULL){
      $user = user_load($form['uid']['#value']);
      $form['actions']['done']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_publish_submit';
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_publish_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $nid = $form['nid']['#value'];
    $node = node_load($nid, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE);
    node_publish_action($node, $context = array());
}
```

but it's not working. My debug text shows up so I know the submit handler is getting called. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't *think* `node_publish_action()` saves the node after setting `$node->status = NODE_PUBLISHED;` so I'd do a `node_save($node);` after it and see what happens.

Comment: Hm. The API page has a comment that specifically says that's not necessary, but it appears to be wrong.

Comment: That comment was in regard to pass by reference I believe.  I *think* again these _action() functions are just stubs for Action to use.  I would just load the node, set the publish flag/field and resave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to [this comment on the API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_publish_action/7#comment-25423), [`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) **is** required after `node_publish_action()` is called.

So the submit handler should look like this:

```
function mymodule_publish_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $nid = $form['nid']['#value'];
  $node = node_load($nid, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE);
  node_publish_action($node, $context = array());
  node_save($node);
}
```

As pointed out by jimajamma, the previous code contains a `hook_action()` which allows integration with Actions. The following code does the same thing, but doesn't use the `hook_action()`

```
function mymodule_publish_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $nid = $form['nid']['#value'];
  $node = node_load($nid, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE);
  $node->status = 1; // 0 = unpublished, 1 = published. There are no other states
  node_save($node);
}
```

Pretty simple.